# How to install Riak on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: package-management

Has anyone been able to install `riak` from the `basho` package? I'm [following the instructions specified here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/installation/Installing-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu/) and am getting *403 Forbidden* errors during update:

```
erturne@node10:~$ curl http://apt.basho.com/gpg/basho.apt.key | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1016  100  1016    0     0   4256      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13546
OK
erturne@node10:~$ sudo bash -c "echo deb http://apt.basho.com $(lsb_release -sc) main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho.list"
erturne@node10:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://apt.basho.com quantal InRelease     
Ign http://apt.basho.com quantal Release.gpg   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Ign http://apt.basho.com quantal Release       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en  
Err http://apt.basho.com quantal/main i386 Packages                  
  403  Forbidden
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://apt.basho.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://apt.basho.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.basho.com/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
erturne@node10:~$ sudo apt-get install riak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package riak
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aditya's answer is good, but if you really want a package you can build your own .deb and install it using dpkg. Start by following Aditya's instructions for getting dependencies (e.g. erlang). Then:

1. Clone the riak source code

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/basho/riak.git
   ```
2. Build

   ```
   cd riak
   make package RELEASE=1
   ```
3. Install

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i package/packages/riak_1.3.0rc2-f87560a7-1_i386.deb
   ```

The name of your .deb file will probably be different than mine.

Answer (score 4):

The Basho Apt Repository doesn't provide packages for Quantal (12.10) and hence it is returning [403 Forbidden Errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). You can verify it by going to http://apt.basho.com/dists, as you can see that the directory for `quantal` is not present.

[image: Basho Apt Repository]

So, the best option before you is to install Riak from Source. Follow the instructions mentioned on their Official Website.

- [Installing Riak from Source](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/installation/Installing-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu/#Installing-Riak-From-Source)

I am summarizing the installation instructions for you here. Open your Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). Then follow as below:

1. Install dependencies for Riak:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev-i386 git
   ```
2. [Install Erlang from Source](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/):

   - Get the necessary development libraries:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses5-dev openssl libssl-dev
     ```
   - Download and build Erlang:

     ```
     wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz
     tar zxvf otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz
     cd otp_src_R15B01
     ./configure && make && sudo make install
     ```
3. Download and install Riak:

   ```
   wget http://downloads.basho.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/riak/1.3/1.3.0/riak-1.3.0.tar.gz
   tar zxvf riak-1.3.0.tar.gz
   cd riak-1.3.0
   make rel
   ```
4. If the build was successful, a fresh build of Riak will exist in the `rel/riak` directory.

Comment: Building from source is not the problem. I'd like to be able to install a package because it simplifies installing riak via Puppet on all the nodes of my cluster.

Comment: On the instructions it says that for non LTS releases it's safe to use the same instructions as the previous LTS release. So this should be possible?

Comment: @giovannibotta Yes.. You should be able to build from source without any problems.